# ReactNative - Is it possible to have nested NavigatorIOS with Modals

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm currently using NavigatorIOS to handle navigation within my app. Though I've come across a situation where I need to present a Modal which also needs to have its own Navigation stack too.

This partially works, until you need to actually push a new component inside the modal (using the nested NavigatorIOS). Pushing a new component results in:

[image]

Has anyone managed to get this kind of nested NavigatorIOS to work?

Code snippets:

Main component render() method:

```
render() {
    return <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.navigationContainer}
        barTintColor={Colors.primaryColor}
        titleTextColor={Colors.white}
        navigationBarHidden={true}
        initialRoute=
            {{
                title: "Main View",
                component: MainComponent,
                backButtonTitle: 'Back',
            }}
    />;
};
```

Inside MainComponent, a Modal is presented with a nested NavigatorIOS inside the render method as such:

```
 <Modal
        animated={this.state.animated}
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}>
        <NavigatorIOS
            style={{flex:1}}
            initialRoute=
                {{
                    title: "Nested Navigator",
                    component: NestedNavigator,
                    backButtonTitle: 'Back',
                }}
        />
  </Modal>
```

Then inside the NestedNavigator component, if you try to push any new component onto the nested stack, you'll get the error posted above.

Though if you dismiss the Error, you can see the new component was actually pushed onto the stack just fine...

Comment: On a side note, using a regular Navigator instead of the NavigatorIOS for the nested navigation works fine. Though, am not a fan of the slight difference in push animation of the Navigator. :(